# Powershell imported module command not recognized

Tags: powershell

I've been working on a powershell script. Because I want to modularize/organize my code a little bit I decided to try making some modules to split up my script.

I am running powershell 5.1.14393.1066

Now I have one main script which imports the modules that it needs, but it can't seem to find my function `Is-Template-Name-Set`:

```
Is-Template-Name-Set : The term 'Is-Template-Name-Set' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\niels\test1\TemplateScript.ps1:6 char:5
+ If (Is-Template-Name-Set) {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Is-Template-Name-Set:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

`Is-Template-Name-Set` is defined in UtilityTemplateModule. Module file (`UtilityTemplateModule.psm1`):

```
Function Get-ScriptDirectory() {
    return Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}

Function Is-Template-Name-Set($templateName) {
    $templateName -And $templateName -is [String] -And -Not $templateName -eq ""
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Get-*'
Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Is-*'
```

UtilityTemplateModule description (`UtilityTemplateModule.psd1` file):

```
@{
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
GUID = '082fc8f7-4c7f-4d9f-84a8-b36c3610cdfe'
Author = 'Niels Bokmans'
CompanyName = 'Bluenotion'
Copyright = 'Copyright (c) 2017'
Description = 'General utilities used by the other template modules.'
# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = '*'

# Cmdlets to export from this module
CmdletsToExport = '*'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'
}
```

My main script:

```
param([String]$templateName="")
Import-Module BuildTemplateModule
Import-Module CdnTemplateModule
Import-Module UtilityTemplateModule

If (Is-TemplateNameSet -templateName $templateName) {
    echo "Template name is set!"
    $templateId = GetTemplateId -templateName $templateName
    if (-Not $templateId -eq -1) {
        Restore-Packages
        Run-Build-Tasks
        Minify-Require-Js
        Clean-Downloaded-Dependencies
        Copy-Offline-Page
        #Deploy $response.templateId
    }
} else {
    echo "Template name not set!"
    exit
}
```

I'm very new to any powershell work and I'm not sure why the function isn't recognized. I think I'm doing it right, exporting functions in the module itself and also just exporting everything in the description file (?, the .psd1 file).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the module named `UtilityTemplateModule` or `UtilityModule`? You seem to refer to both.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistencies, the module is in a file named `UtilityTemplateModule.psm1` in a folder named `UtilityTemplateModule` in the system32 powershell modules directory.

Comment: I think this might be wrong `Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Get-*'` as I don't think you can necessarily use a wildcard string with it like that. Might be mistaken though.

Comment: In the interests of testing change `Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Is-*'` to `Export-ModuleMember -Function 'Is-Template-Name-Set'`

Comment: It's generally better practice just to list each Function under `CmdletsToExport = '*'` in the PSD1 (instead of *) as this makes them autodiscoverable and the module then doesn't have to be explicitly loaded.

Comment: Okay, should they be under `FunctionsToExport` or `CmdletsToExport`, and are they just comma-separated?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the difference, maybe it's that cmdletstoexport is if you are using an advanced function. So I guess functionstoexport. And yes I think just a comma separated string.

Comment: Alright, I explicitly listed it under `FunctionsToExport` - `Get-Module -ListAvailable` shows the `Is-Template-Name-Set` command, but still the same error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Manually importing the module (i.e. `Import-Module "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\UtilityTemplateModule\UtilityTemplateModule.psm1"` does work (until I restart the ISE session)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about the system32 powershell modules directory I think you may be putting your modules in the wrong directory.

Per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

`$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)`

> This location is reserved for modules that ship with Windows. Do not install modules to this location.

I suggest moving your modules to:

```
$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)
```

Or

```
$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)
```

Creating any directories in either of those paths that are missing (e.g under `Documents` the `\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folders don't usually exist by default).

Alternatively you could put modules in a custom path and add that path to the `PSModulePath` environment variable.

Comment: I moved the modules to `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` but it still can't find them. When I run `GetModule -ListAvailable` they show up though.

Comment: Are you working in the same console/ISE window for a long time? If so the `Import-Module` commands might not be be actually loading the latest version of your modules. You can workaround this by adding `-force` or doing `Remove-Module` for them first. Just a thought.

Comment: Just restarted the ISE window but that wasn't it either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I was missing the `RootModule` property.
It should point to your primary `.psm1` file.